# Scheduled job at a specific time is running at another time as scheduled as well

Tags: schedulebatch

by monitoring of a batch job, we saw that this job started outside the scheduled time. For example, we scheduled the batch job to run at 9:00 am. However, when we checked the list of apex batch jobs, we saw the job started one at 3:00 am, although we haven't started it at that time.

How can this happen, even when you have scheduled a batch job to run at a specif time, it ran once at another time, and again at the scheduled time?.

I would appreciate your answers, guy, because there are some things in Salesforce which are not documented and no idea what't going on here.

Another point: at the same time another batch job was running, but the parallel running job has to do with Accounts. Our job has to do with a child object, Account vouchers.

It seems to be both collide causing the errors UNABLE_LOCK_ROW.

Does anybody have an idea

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Did you follow the answer on your earlier question

Comment: Hi Santanu, you marked my question as duplicated and this is not a duplicated question. Before you mark a question as duplicate you should understand the content in the question. That's very mean of you.